# How to add buttons underneath a Xamarin.Forms list view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I have an app i'm doing in xamrian forms and I have a card styled list view. I want to be able to add 3 buttons underneath the listview one on the left one in the center and one on the right 
here's my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.HomePage">
  <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
            <Frame.Content>
              <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Frame.Content>
                  <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Image
                          HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                          Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           TextColor="#69add1"
                           FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                           FontSize="24"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
              </Frame>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>  

          </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
  </ContentPage>
```

How would I go about doing this in xaml?

Thank's in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox_Forms"
             x:Class="Sandbox_Forms.MainPage">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
      <!-- Add bindings and data template -->
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
      <Button Text="Button1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
      <Button Text="Button2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
      <Button Text="Button3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

This will limit your `ListView` to only fill the space that your buttons do not occupy. The output should look something like this:
[image: UWP Desktop sample]

Comment: Thanks for the response I have tried your suggestion and nothing shows up in the app any other suggestions? thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Curious - works fine for me. I updated my answer to be more concrete - the aqua background should be telling, but keep an eye on your output window for binding errors & the like and let me know what you see. At the very least, you should be able to see the buttons, even if there is a problem with your listview. Double checking your snippet, do you bind your listview to an object outside the view? Not sure how it will receive content otherwise.

Comment: what does you binding code behind look like? I'm not binding anything to the gridview could that be the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't need anything for the grid. You'll need to set the `ItemSource` property on the listview and have it set to whatever property on your model has the collection you want to show. Here's a quick primer from the folks at Xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackLayout>
  <ListView>
    ...
  </ListView>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I tried your suggestion but nothing shows up under the listview any other suggestions?